# Задавать мелодию - чего или чему?

Tags: управление, выбор-варианта

> И тогда из садов Ватикана начинает долетать лёгкий шепот невиданных
>   птах. И они не возносятся, не перелетают с ветки на ветку. Они
>   посвистывают, словно **задают мелодию дню**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В толковом словаре Д. В. Дмитриева:
[задавать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/1320/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
4. Если какая-то часть произведения искусства задает тон всего произведения [**чего?**] (всему произведению [**чему?**]), значит, эта часть определяет характер всего произведения, является ключевой для его настроения, содержания.

*Это ироничное описание портрета героя сразу **задаёт** общий **тон повествования.**

Эта пьеса **задала тон** всему музыкальному **циклу.***

Получается, что оба варианта возможны.
Но я бы остановилась на том, который есть — [птахи] **задают мелодию дню**. Мне он больше нравится. Да и встречается нечасто — как раз для Вашего нестандартного повествования.

Comment: Лорочка, у туточки - https://ridero.ru/books/obryvki_iz_realnostei_potegurim/ - есть *бесплатный фрагмент*, его я и читаю. И пока можно вносить правку. Как выправим всё - будем делать бумажную книжку. Если у Вас откроется ссылка, знайте: это пока без заключительной корректуры (найденное ещё не внесено в текст).

Comment: Спасибо, все читабельно. Значит, мы своими советами тоже маленько участвуем?.. Обратите внимание (об авторе): _Инга Ильм — актриса и телеведущая, историк искусств и просто путе**щ**ественница._ Надо бы подправить.

Comment: О! Обложки я и не приметил! Знаменитая ошибка: ЭНЦИКЛОПУДИЯ. Увидел наборщик, случайно, когда вовсю печатался тираж. Спасибо, Римуля-Лорхен! )))